# Can Photoshop export artboards as a spritesheet?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, artboard, image-sprite

I have several artboards in my PSD file, and I would like to create a spritesheet from them. All artboards have identical dimensions and are composed of several layers.

Now, I'm aware that there is a way to [export a sequence of layers](http://blogs.adobe.com/edge/2014/09/18/export-sprite-sheet-from-adobe-photoshop/) to a spritesheet, or to use [online tools](https://draeton.github.io/stitches/) to stitch images together, but I'd like to export whole artboards, not individual layers, and also export them as a single file containing all images stacked one next to another. It would be far more convenient if there is a similar option built inside Photoshop, or even if there is a script for it.

Is there a way to export all artboards as a single spritesheet directly from Photoshop?

Comment: Could you use Photoshop Contact Sheet and select all of the images that would go on the spritesheet? (Photoshop) Choose File > Automate > Contact Sheet II.

Comment: @AndrewH Unfortunately, no. Contact Sheet messes up the dimensions, and doesn't remove the space between artboards. If I have a gap of 300 px (exaggerated, of course) between artboards, that same gap will show scaled in the result. If I have them placed in a diagonal inside of a file, they will all come out in a diagonal in the result. Basically, it just scales down the entire document, and places it on to a defined sheet. It does what it's supposed to: it makes _a contact sheet_, and a pretty good one, but that's not what I need.